# Configure TortoiseGit to pull all submodules when pulling superproject

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-pull, tortoisegit

I'm looking for a 1 click option in TortoiseGit for pulling the parent project as well as updating all the submodules <strike>to point to the latest HEAD</strike>.  I know you can do the following after a **pull** with the drop down menu . . .

[image]

Is there a way to integrate the **Update Submodules** command to run automatically after a **pull** command?  Or git-config option? Or server side option? Or script hook option?

I see the hook options in the TortoiseGit settings but only for commit and push commands, nothing for pull . . .

[image]

Right now I'm just executing a script with a few git commands to accomplish what I want.  Here's the commands that I'm running in the script at the moment that works . . .

```
git submodule foreach git checkout master
git submodule foreach git pull
git pull origin
```

I was wondering if there was something in TortoiseGit that would accomplish the same thing?

EDIT: response to MrTux

[image]

Comment: Submodule update is something different, it updates the submodules to the versions as specified in the HEAD and is not the same as a pull in the submodules.

Comment: Most likely I'm just using the wrong terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could configure Git to update submodules on pull automatically:
`git config submodule.recurse true` or `git config --global submodule.recurse true`.

How the modules are updated (to which branch etc.) can be controlled using [.gitmodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules)

As of TortoiseGit 2.13 there is no support for `git submodule foreach git pull`

Comment: This is what I'm looking for!  Although when I configure this, I get an unclean exit when I perform a pull.  I'll post a screenshot in my post.

Comment: The error that you get is a regression of Git.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to resolve?

Comment: Use Git < 2.38 or wait until the fix is released in Git.

Comment: The known issue https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/-/issues/3978